# Can a user link to multiple tenants in Abp.io?

Tags: abp

As I understood, in the latest Abp Framework, a user can link to only one tenant right?
I wonder how to customize ABP so that a user can link to multiple tenants?
I have a scenario as below:

1. The admin create a new account for a user and assign him to 2 or more organizations (multiple tenants).
2. He can use this account to login to multiple tenants and can access data corresponding to each tenant

Many thanks!

Comment: You can link to users under multiple tenants or users in Host.
https://github.com/abpframework/abp/blob/dev/modules/identity/src/Volo.Abp.Identity.Domain/Volo/Abp/Identity/IdentityLinkUser.cs

Comment: I have checked Abp source code and also this article https://github.com/abpframework/abp/issues/2611
but the problem is: you still have to create multiple user accounts: create user at host level and create users for each tenant and then link host user to every tenant user.
Now if the user change password, we have to change password for host user and all tenant users also. The same when the user change profile or other user settings.